# How to share fragments through activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, share

I need a way to share Fragments through different activities, so for example I have MainActivity with a Fragment and when I go to SecondActivity I need that same Fragment loaded, but the Fragment can vary so it would not always be the same one.

I've guessed that I could get the actual Fragments id or tag and pass it on the Intent so I could retrieve it on SecondActivity and use it to load the correct Fragment, but I don't know how.

Comment: in SecondActivity you should instantiate a fragment the same way you do it in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to create a new instance for the fragment and load again the data in it. If you created the fragment in a good way, it is a really simple task. The reasons why you can't reuse the fragment are the following:

- If you could do something like that, what would happend to this fragment's lifecycle? What about going back from current activity to the other? Everything can be messed up.
- Every activity has its own `FragmentManager` and they are never shared between activities, so you can't ask in another's activity for a fragment that doesn't belongs to it.

If you have some doubts on how to pass data using intents between activities to tell the fragment what to load, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) post.